# AWS CDK CodePipeline S3 Source set Detection Option to Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I am using AWS CDK to create a **S3SourceAction** in AWS CodePipeline as shown in the screenshot attached.  However this is using **AWS CodePipeline** as the detection option. How can I make the detection option **Amazon CloudWatch Events** via CDK? [image]

Here is my current code for the S3SourceAction.

```
const sourceAction = new S3SourceAction({

  actionName: 'S3ConfigSource',

  bucket: bucketConfigFiles,

  bucketKey: zippedConfigsDir,

  output: sourceOutput,

  role: codeDeployRole,

});
```

Or if that’s not possible is there another way via CDK to automatically have my Pipeline run on changes to a S3 Bucket file?

Answer (score 0):

In your sourceAction creation just add `trigger: codepipeline_actions.S3Trigger.EVENTS`

```
const sourceAction = new S3SourceAction({
  actionName: 'S3ConfigSource',
  bucket: bucketConfigFiles,
  bucketKey: zippedConfigsDir,
  output: sourceOutput,
  trigger: codepipeline_actions.S3Trigger.EVENTS,
  role: codeDeployRole,

});
```

From CDK documentation, these are trigger options:

- `NONE`    The Action will never detect changes - the Pipeline it's part of will only begin a run when explicitly started.
- `POLL`    CodePipeline will poll S3 to detect changes.
- `EVENTS`  CodePipeline will use CloudWatch Events to be notified of changes.